# How to call a function/module in Electron from my webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'll try to describe a minimized question in short paragraphs.

In short, I want to use some logic or call some functions in my Electron App from the webpage that is **in** my Electron App (I am actually wrapping an electron app 'shell' for my webpage).

Suppose I want to expose a function in my Electron app. Say,

```
function printNumbers () {
  console.log(1)
}
```

notice that it should be located in my Electron code.

Then after running my app, I'd like to call this function from my webpage(clicking a button in my webpage which is loaded from a website, then open a new window in my Electron App). For now, I think I can check whether printNumber works by using the developer console.

I have checked how to use `remote` module to call functions/modules inside electron. But I didn't find a way to call a function I write in my electron code base.

BTW:
I can enable the `nodeIntegration` option.

Comment: @nem035 Thanks for pointing the ambiguous description out. It's the second case you mentioned.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two main ways to communicate between the renderer process and the main process.

**1.** One way would be to use the [remote](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md) module to require the code you want to take from the main process. This object will contain anything you export from your main process code.

```
// main process, for example app/main.js
exports.test = () => console.log('Yay');

// renderer process, for example app/renderer.js
const { remote } = require('electron');
const mainProcess = remote.require('./main.js');

mainProcess.test(); // 'Yay'
```

**2.** Another way would be to use [Inter Process Communication](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md) to send/receive events between the main process and the renderer process:

```
// main process, for example app/main.js
myWindow.webContents.send('my-cool-log-event', 'Yay');

// renderer process, for example app/renderer.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.on('my-cool-log-event', (evt, msg) => console.log(msg)); // 'Yay'
```

---

If you want to call a function from the main process when a click event fires in a renderer process, you can use either approach.

*1.*

```
// main process, for example app/main.js
exports.onClick = () => console.log('Yay');

// renderer process, for example app/renderer.js
const { remote } = require('electron');
const mainProcess = remote.require('./main.js');

document
  .querySelector('#elem')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    mainProcess.onClick();
  });
```

*2.*

```
// main process, for example app/main.js
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('click', () => console.log('do something'));

// renderer process, for example app/renderer.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

document
  .querySelector('#elem')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('click');
  });
```

Comment: still valid answer with option 2 in 2021 :)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to kill any running function in electron?