# Electron call from renderer to main

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

As answered in [How to call a function/module in Electron from my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819632/how-to-call-a-function-module-in-electron-from-my-webpage) I tried it but code requires electron.

```js
const { remote } = require('electron');
const mainProcess = remote.require('./main.js');

mainProcess.test();
```

I have renderer as separate repository and get error on building:

```
10 silly lifecycle scratch-desktop@3.6.0~build-gui: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./scripts/run-in-gui.js build' ]
11 silly lifecycle scratch-desktop@3.6.0~build-gui: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle scratch-desktop@3.6.0~build-gui: Failed to exec build-gui script
13 verbose stack Error: scratch-desktop@3.6.0 build-gui: `node ./scripts/run-in-gui.js build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\caxap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\caxap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid scratch-desktop@3.6.0
15 verbose cwd D:\scratch-desktop
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "D:\\Awork\\Apps simple\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\caxap\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-gui"
18 verbose node v13.0.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error scratch-desktop@3.6.0 build-gui: `node ./scripts/run-in-gui.js build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the scratch-desktop@3.6.0 build-gui script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

```
Module not found: Error: 
Can't resolve 'fs' in 
'D:\scratch-desktop\node_modules\scratch-gui\node_modules\scratch-vm\node_modules\electron'
```

Dependency graph: scratch-desktop (electron) -> scratch-gui -> scratch-vm (from where I call)

Comment: What is in your `main.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

To better answer this question it would help to post your package.json and make sure electron is in your dependencies. If not, npm install electron, if yes try this below:

You need 2 things in order for the ipcRenderer and ipcMain to work

in your main app/main.js you need to require ipcMain

`const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');`

And in your renderer process you should require it like so:

`const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');`

Comment: vm: electron in dependencies, desktop: electron in devdependencies