# Call an Electron function of renderer or main process from online website

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron

An Electron app has a `<webview>` component inside a renderer process.

IPC is used to communicate between the main process and the renderer process without using `remote` module. (nodeIntegration=false too)

The `<webview>` shows an online website (html) under my control.

I want to call a specific function in either `renderer` process or `main` process from the online website.

For example,

**[Online HTML webpage]**

```
<script>
var arg1 = ....getAsyncFrom...(); // need to fetch from web
function callHandler(arg1, arg2...) {
 window.myElectronApp.callHandlerFromWeb(arg1, arg2);
}
</script>
```

**[Electron app (maybe in a renderer process)]**

```
let myWebViewControl = document.getElementById('myWebView');

// for security reason, "callHandlerFromWeb" is explicitly nominated
sampleCallBack.response("callHandlerFromWeb", (arg1, arg2..) => {
 callHandlerInsideElectron(arg1, arg2...);
});

    function callHandlerInsideElectron(arg1, arg2) {
     console.log("Handler called from webpage" + arg1 + arg2);
    }
```

(I am not asking how to call a main process function from a renderer process. But, how can I call an Electron app's function with arguments from online website inside `webview`.)

**+** Exactly the same thing that I am looking for is possible in Flutter Webview. This is neither a new nor 'dangerous' thing.

Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't do that, as it would be a huge security problem (imagine if any given webpage could communicate with any random application on your device). However, you can create and open a link with your own "protocol" (such as `my-app://`) via Electron's features for that, see [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol). Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Additionally, it's not about an arbitrary/random function. I don't mean that `myElectronApp.ANY_FUNCTIONS_IN_ELECTRONS();` is my goal. However, like an IPC model, there can be some specific functions for that purpose. I've edited the question a little bit more specific.

Comment: I understand that. The "arbitrary" part applied to webpages and applications on your device. If you could call into your Electron application from within the browser, so could any other webpage call into any other application. Calling specific functions should be feasible through custom protocols; see the docs I've linked - incidentally, the usage is pretty similar to your pseudocode.

Comment: I guess you want to do that in response of an action inside the hosted website: You may use preload script with your webview. In this preload in response to an Ipc message after you are sure the webview content had been loaded you can add a onclick function to the element you want to trigger this action.

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE That's similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819632/how-to-call-a-function-module-in-electron-from-my-webpage I need more than onlick thing. Triggering by onclick is what I can do already, while, calling a function with Arguments(from hosted webpage, not from Electron app) is what I am looking for.